# how to get the text from a text box using formCollection, that gets its value from a dropdown using jquery

Tags: sql, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have a textbox which gets its value from a dropdown using jquery. I want that value to be saved in database using formcollection. But I get '0' when I get its value.

here, is the textbox;

```
<input type="number" name="Total" id="Total" disabled="disabled" style="width: 70px;" />
```

and here is the ajax code that gets the value from dropdown and shows it in the textbox;

```
function getValue() {
    var value = $("#CityDDL").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Admin/yourActionMethod',
        data: { 'id': value },
        type: "post",
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            $('#Total').val(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            $('#Total').text("Error encountered while getting total");
        }
    });
}
```

Now, im doing this to save that value in database;

```
am.TotalAmount =  Convert.ToInt32(fc["Total"]);
```

but in debugging mode, it shows 0.

Comment: Instead of disabled try readonly for the textbox, it will work

Comment: Which value Did you get from CityDDL in "var value = $("#CityDDL").val();" this line?